# Interpolation of missing values

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to implement a for loop which loops over a dictionary. This dictionary has values extracted from a csv file. Some of the values at some rows are missing. What I am thinking of doing is taking the average of previous and nearest available next entry and assigning it to the dictionary. Sometimes there is a missing column value for consecutive rows.

Here is an example:

**input.csv:**

```
Date,Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
2020-06-26,1,3,5
2020-06-27,2,,4
2020-06-28,5,,6
2020-06-29,7,8,10
```

The expected behaviour is:

**output.csv:**

```
Date,Column_1,Column_2,Column_3
2020-06-26,1,3,5
2020-06-27,2,5.5,4
2020-06-28,5,6.75,6
2020-06-29,7,8,10
```

(3 + 8) / 2 = 5.5

(5.5 + 8) / 2 = 6.75

Here is I have tried:

```py
def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    previous_item = None
    current_item = next(iterator)
    for next_item in iterator:
        yield previous_item, current_item, next_item
        previous_item = current_item
        current_item = next_item
    yield previous_item, current_item, None

dictionary = {
    '2020-06-26': {'Date': '2020-06-26', 'Column_1': 1, 'Column_2': 3, 'Column_3': 5},
    '2020-06-27': {'Date': '2020-06-27', 'Column_1': 2, 'Column_3': 4},
    '2020-06-28': {'Date': '2020-06-28', 'Column_1': 5, 'Column_3': 6},
    '2020-06-29': {'Date': '2020-06-29', 'Column_1': 7, 'Column_2': 8, 'Column_3': 10}
}

field_names = {'Column_1', 'Column_2', 'Column_3'}

for previous_date, current_date, next_date in neighborhood(sorted(dictionary)):
    for field_name in field_names:
        if field_name not in dictionary[current_date]:
            dictionary[current_date][field_name] = (dictionary[previous_date][field_name] + dictionary[next_date][field_name]) / 2
```

**Note:** The question is not about how to read from a csv file or writing to a csv file. There will be a dictionary with data that I have extracted from the input csv file, and there is a code after this code snippet which will write to the output csv file. The reason why I made the dictionary has the date twice is because when reading from the input csv file I am doing this: `dictionary[row['Date']] = row`, I can make it a list but it will complicate the `sorted` function call. It is given that the first and the last rows are guaranteed to be filled completely, i.e. without missing column values. The dictionary key is a `datetime` object and not a string. When I am reading from the input csv file I am converting the string to a `datetime` object and assigning it as a key of the dictionary.

Comment: Can you use pandas?

Comment: @funnydman I am allowed to use pandas, but I have no experience with this library.

Comment: Beware: this is a poor interpolation method, because it is non linear if you have more than one missing consecutive value. A linear method would give: 3 - 4.67 [3 + (8-5)/3] - 6.33 [3 + 2*(8-5)/3] - 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pandas you can use the [`interpolate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) method.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
```

The dataframe now looks like this:

```
         Date  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0  2020-06-26         1       3.0         5
1  2020-06-27         2       NaN         4
2  2020-06-28         5       NaN         6
3  2020-06-29         7       8.0        10
```

Using `interpolate()` on the column with missing data fills the gaps.

```
df['Column_2'].interpolate()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0    3.000000
1    4.666667
2    6.333333
3    8.000000
Name: Column_2, dtype: float64
```

Now we can assign that back into the dataframe

```
df['Column_2'] = df['Column_2'].interpolate()
```

Results in

```
         Date  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0  2020-06-26         1  3.000000         5
1  2020-06-27         2  4.666667         4
2  2020-06-28         5  6.333333         6
3  2020-06-29         7  8.000000        10
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can not use this approach because I am converting the `Date` column to a `datetime` object. Also, I want to sort the data based on the date before interpolating. I will try to solve these two issues and will let you know if it worked or not. Also, I have noticed that the interpolated values are different than the average between the previous and the nearest next known value.

Comment: You can make columns into datetime objects by simply applying the to_datetime function `df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)`. Also the interpolate method can use different algorithms for filling the missing data, have a look at the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Answer (score 1):

`Python` is a object-friendly language, so a little complex problem will be ok to use `class` to slove.

Solution:

```py
class frame(object):
    def __init__(self, data:"list of list of object"= None):
        self._data = data
        self._init_str_size()

    def _init_str_size(self):
        # assert that it have at least one object.
        assert self._data[0]
        self._str_size = [0 for i in range(len(self._data[0]))]
        for index, col in enumerate(self._data):
            self._str_size[index] = max(self._str_size[index], len(str(col[index])))

    def __str__(self):
        result = []
        for col in self._data:
            result.append(" | ".join([
                f"{str(item):>{self._str_size[index]}}" for index, item in enumerate(col)
            ]))
        return "\n".join(result)

    def _before_num(self, i, j):
        return self._before_num(i - 1, j) if self._data[i][j] == None else self._data[i][j]

    def _next_num(self, i, j):
        return self._next_num(i + 1, j) if self._data[i][j] == None else self._data[i][j]

    def fill_num(self):
        for r in range(len(self._data)):
            for c in range(len(self._data[r])):
                if self._data[r][c] == None:
                    print(self._before_num(r, c), self._next_num(r, c))
                    self._data[r][c] = (
                        (self._before_num(r, c) + self._next_num(r, c)) / 2
                    )
        self._init_str_size()

f = frame([
    ["2020-06-26", 1,  3.0,  5],
    ["2020-06-27", 2, None,  4],
    ["2020-06-28", 5, None,  6],
    ["2020-06-29", 7,  8.0, 10]
])

print(f)
# output:
#   | 2020-06-26 | 1 |  3.0 |  5
#   | 2020-06-27 | 2 | None |  4
#   | 2020-06-28 | 5 | None |  6
#   | 2020-06-29 | 7 |  8.0 | 10

# the 2-row and 3-col number's before number and next number
print(f._before_num(2 - 1, 3 - 1))
print(f._next_num(2 - 1, 3 - 1))
# output:
#   | 3.0
#   | 8.0

f.fill_num()
print(f)
# output:
#   | 2020-06-26 | 1 |   3.0 |  5
#   | 2020-06-27 | 2 |   5.5 |  4
#   | 2020-06-28 | 5 |  6.75 |  6
#   | 2020-06-29 | 7 |   8.0 | 10
```

I program a lot to try to show it in good format. But the core code to fill itself just use a little place. Enjoying youself.